# Does Polars support predicate pushdown with Deltalate?

Tags: delta-lake, python-polars

I'm trying to load a Deltalake table in Python in a memory-bound environment (k8s Pod with memory limit) with [Polars](https://www.pola.rs/), I am getting an OOM exception when trying to do a `scan_delta(...).head().collect()`.

I am unable to determine if predicate pushdown works and/or is implemented in Polars for Deltalake, or if my code is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does. However your query doesn't have a predicate (filter block), so there is no predicate pushdown.

Limits (the head call) are not yet pushed down in delta table. We can add that later.